# Django Email issues while sending to others

Tags: django, django-email

@ Code is in settings.py and removed the line in the settings.py EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend

```
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'xxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='app-specific-pass-word'
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_PORT= 587
```

My question is if any current user login in the application(like leave application) and he raise a request other user have received the emails notification from the application, but why mail is going to the EMAIL_HOST_USER= ‘xxx@gmail.com’ instead of current login user email id .

I need to other person receive from the current login user email id not from the “EMAIL_HOST_USER”

Thanks

Comment: How did you send the email?

Comment: send from button click event html format code.